# Calculating an improper integral involving $\log$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Could somebody help me to solve the integral below?
$$\int\limits_0^1\frac{\ln x}{x^{a}(1-x)^{b}}\,\mathrm{d}x,$$
where $a,b \in (0,1)$.
It may be helpful to know the definition of the Beta function:
$$\textbf{B}(r,s):=\int\limits_0^1x^{r-1}(1-x)^{s-1}\mathrm{d}x, \quad r,s>0.$$

Thanks!

Comment: For $0<\{a,b\}<1$, *Mathematica* gives integral as:  $$\frac{\Gamma (1-a) \Gamma (1-b) \left(H_{-a}-H_{-a-b+1}\right)}{\Gamma (-a-b+2)}$$ where $H$ denotes the Harmonic Number.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork : So what is $H_{-a}$ for $0<a<1$?  [M'ma's documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HarmonicNumber.html) is silent on the issue and M'ma leaves `HarmonicNumber[-1/2]` unevaluated.

Comment: I too read the *Mathematica* documentation, but when I plug in values for $-1<a<0$, I get real numbers (without error message).

Comment: @DavidG.Stork : When I plug in approximate values, I get approximate values out, but the $a = b = 1/2$ case should resolve `HarmonicNumber[-1/2]` to entirely familiar numbers, in particular, `-Log[4]`.  However, again, I get `HarmonicNumber[-1/2]` left unevaluated.  I'd be far more likely to believe M'ma's result if it were (1) able to exactly evaluate those $H$s for exact inputs for which it can exactly evaluate the integral and (2) possessing definitions of those $H$s.

Comment: *Mathematica* evaluates the Harmonic number for decimal (real) numbers ($-1<x<1$) but not for rationals.  I think this is a minor glitch, and recommend one simply use decimal arguments.

Comment: Why not use differentiation under the integral sign? Define $I(a)=\int_0^1 \log(ax)x^{-a}(1-x)^{-b}dx$. Differentiate wrt $a$ to evaluate integral. Finding an initial value may be a little challenging though.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork : The [Harmonic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number) can be represented as an integral and a series via analytic continuation, extends the definition to the complex plane other than the negative integers $x$.
$$
{H_x} = \int_0^1 {\frac{{1 - {t^x}}}{{1 - t}}dt =  - \sum\limits_{k = 1}^\infty  {\left( \begin{array}{l}
x\\
k
\end{array} \right)\frac{{{{\left( { - 1} \right)}^k}}}{k}} } 
$$

Answer (score 0):

It is straightforward to see by differentiation under the integral that we have

\begin{align}I(a,b)&=\int_0^1\frac{\ln(x)}{x^a(1-x)^b}~\mathrm dx\\&=\frac\partial{\partial a}\int_0^1\frac1{x^a(1-x)^b}~\mathrm dx\\&=\frac\partial{\partial a}\mathbf B(1-a,1-b)\end{align}

which can further be written out using the Gamma function and it's derivatives given in terms of the digamma function.

Answer (score -1):

This sounds like homework, and you did not include what you have done.

Anyway, another way to write this in terms of the beta function and its derivative is to integrate by parts.